# Would an "affector" be appropriate for an event driver?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm trying to come up with a better word to describe a "driver" or "conditional"; basically, the name of an object or event which is a trigger for something else.

Would it be appropriate to say that a button which turns on a light is an affector? If I believe I understand its usage in this context, it would only be an affector while triggering the event (the button is pressed).

I've been unable to find support to convince me that this is the appropriate use of the word.

Comment: Is this a coinage of your own? It's a (now rare) variant of *http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affecter* along with some jargon uses, though I don't know it as programming jargon (and I do know event-based programming). Also, you seem to be talking about the source of an event, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure. It sounds like a word I've heard before which is why I'm confused as to why I can't find much in the way of support. I don't like "driver" as it sounds like the operator of an automobile. And "conditional" is confusing as it is a valid definition for referring to both the cause and effect. There is a very real difference between "affect" and "effect" which is why it sounds so right to me.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an _effecter_ (or _effector_ if you wish)? I don't see how _affect_ fits the meaning you're describing. And what's wrong with the far more obvious and fitting _trigger_ (that you even use yourself, twice)?

Comment: If you're coining, I'd recommend avoiding words with phrases even if the *or* spelling variant of *affecter* is obsolete. From your description you seem to be talking about what is already called an event source in existing jargon. Is there a way you differ from that?

Comment: (Without wanting to turn this into a full-blown naming question that is hence off-topic).

Comment: I'm avoiding phrases which might be more accurate such as "event source" because in my case I need it to be a single word to fit consistently in context. Also, I see there being a very different relationship between a driver and a source. For example, I believe a light switch would be the driver but not the *source* of the event. The source would be the person who flips the switch. The affect is the switch being flipped with the effect being the light turning on. That's why I see the switch as the affector of the event sounding appropriate. Am I wrong?

Comment: How do you mean the object is the trigger? The very existence of the object causes something to happen, or that the object has a method that raises or triggers the event?  A button that is flipped to turn on a light is a UI component (whether in the real world or on a computer screen). So it seems you're talking simultaneously about things within the program as well as about the people using the program and the interface between user and program.

Comment: The application for the word is a scenario in which some *conditional* requires an active state for an event to happen. I'm trying to find a synonym that feels less confusing. As I said, *driver* feels too much of a relation to transportation, *conditional* could refer to either a cause or effect, *requirement* feels too harsh, *event* feels too broad and has the same problems as "conditional".

Comment: What's wrong with your own word, *trigger*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACE .. Affect Causes Effect.  In the time line, affects precede the effects.

There are normally many affectors creating the one desired effect.  Affect comes from the cognitive domain.  This means it carries intent and articulated reason.

Effect is more logical; determined after.  Affect is more influential; probable before.

Brian, I disagree.  To change a part of anything is to have an effect.  Plus, what is the difference between change and cause; other than effect and affect.

Answer (score 0):

I think "effector" is right, along with drivers (in CPU operating systems).

Comment: Think about affect and effect. "Affect" would be the driver and "effect" would be the result.

Comment: Not so, Matt. To "affect " something means to change some aspect of it, not to cause it to happen.  I'm not an event-driven programmer (although I used to be a programmer in Visual Basic; I'm now a technical writer in an IT department); but what you're describing sounds to me more like an "actuator", or possibly an "evoker".

Comment: I think there was some confusion. I'm using "driver" as a desired synonym for the word in question. This has nothing to do with programming or computers.